# How can I pattern match to get at the numbers that serde_json has parsed?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I want to convert 3rd party library enums to and from JSON. As I don't want to edit the 3rd party source code I don't want to use the derive macros.

I want to handwrite the serde_json `deserialize` method. I am thinking that pattern matching is the way to go but the things I need to match on are not public:

```
extern crate serde_json;

#[test]
fn test_parse_from_json() {
    let s = r#"{
                    "e": 0,
                    "c": 1,
                    "n": 2
                  }"#;

    let v: Map<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(&s).unwrap();

    match (&v["e"], &v["c"], &v["n"]) {
        (&Value::Number(ref e), &Value::Number(ref c), &Value::Number(ref n)) => {
            // e is a PosInt(u64) but that isn't public to match one nor access its methods!
            let value = e.n; // error[E0616]: field `n` of struct `serde_json::Number` is private
        }
        _ => (),
    }

}
```

That doesn't compile. If I replace that inner bit with something I can set a breakpoint on, I can see in the debugger that `e` is a `Number` which contains a `PosInt(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pattern match on private fields because they are private. You have to use the accessors the library decides to provide. The serde_json documentation for [`Number`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/struct.Number.html) shows that it has methods like [`as_u64`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/struct.Number.html#method.as_u64):

```
let value = e.as_u64().expect("not a u64");
```

---

> As I don't want to edit the 3rd party source code I don't want to use the derive macros.

You may be suffering from the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). For example, the Serde docs describe how to [implement the traits for a "remote type"](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html).

You could also create your own type that you deserialize into and construct a transformation to and from the library type:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Mine {
    e: u64,
    c: u64,
    n: u64,
}

#[test]
fn test_parse_from_json() {
    let s = r#"{
        "e": 0,
        "c": 1,
        "n": 2
    }"#;

    let v: Mine = serde_json::from_str(&s).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", (v.e, v.c, v.n));
}
```

Comment: Coming from a GCed language I would instinctively shy away from using my own structures that mirror someone else's with coping between the two. Is it the case that with Rust that the compiler can optimise things away such that the "own type" approach you suggest can be a zero overhead technique like the newtype pattern?

Comment: @simbo1905 I don't believe that there's any such optimization here, or if there is it's incidental. I don't think that GC or not matters here though. In the end, you deserialize to the local `Mine` struct, then transfer ownership of the bits to the real struct, which should be the same as if you were returning the real struct. I would expect the optimizer to coalesce the move to `Mine` and then the move to `Real`, making it equally efficient. I'd expect much the same from a language like Java or C#.

Comment: Is it possible to pattern match on `serde_json::Value::Object(json!({"a" : a, "b" : b})) => {  use(a, b); }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Shepmaster's answer I got a lot further along:

```
let v: Map<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(&s).unwrap();

let bn: Option<BallotNumber>;

match (&v["e"],&v["c"],&v["n"]) {
    (&Value::Number(ref e),&Value::Number(ref c),&Value::Number(ref n)) => {
        match ( &e.as_u64(), &c.as_u64(), &n.as_u64() ) {
            (&Some(era), &Some(count), &Some(number)) => 
                bn = Some(BallotNumber::new(era, count, number)),
            _ => 
                bn = None
        }
    },
    _ => 
        bn = None
}
```

That does the trick only it looks like a bit of a train smash. Given that @Shepmaster's answer points out that serde provided a way around the Orphan rule I will use that approach.